# How to Resize an Array of Values by Increasing or Decreasing the Frequency of its Elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, resize

Newbie here again, and I apologize for the homework-like quality of this post.

I am not certain if I my title makes perfect sense, but I am trying to enlarge (or reduce, if necessary) an array, by an variable integer, and I am seeking help to understand the math and logic behind it.
(This is supposed to be akin to enlarging an object or reducing by a factor n.)

For instance if there is a 2x2 array, like this:

```
0   1   
2   3
```

I want to be able to multipy it by, say n = 2, and end up with this:

```
0   0   1   1   
0   0   1   1   
2   2   3   3   
2   2   3   3
```

I want to be able to set n to any value and have it "resize" the array by this value (rows and columns should grow and shrink appropriately.)
My code is not working as I envision, and I hope someone can break this down for me (or guide me to where I can find information to do this right).
Here is what I have been able to do so far, which fails as I increase or reduce the resizing value. ( I'm trying to write the arrays into seperate files):

```
 #define enn 2     //resize value.
 //fill the infile with an array contents.
int inArray[SIZE][SIZE];
int count = 0, row, column;
//intialize the array.
for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < SIZE; column++)
    {
        inArray[row][column] = count;
        count += 1;
    }
}
//write to the infile.
for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < SIZE; column++)
    {
        fprintf(infileptr, "%i\t", inArray[row][column]);
    }
    fputs("\n", infileptr);
} 
fclose(infileptr);
//write expanded array to outfile.

for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < SIZE; column++)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < enn; m++)
        {
            fprintf(outfileptr, "%i\t", inArray[row][column]);
        }
    }
    fputs("\n", outfileptr);

    for(column = 0; column < SIZE; column++)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < enn; m++)
        {
            fprintf(outfileptr, "%i\t", inArray[row][column]);
        }
    }
    fputs("\n", outfileptr);
}
fclose(outfileptr);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wow, this would be a perfect job for APL. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To multiply size of array you need 4 nested loops. It' s not enough to print your colums `enn` times, you have to print your rows `enn` times too:

```
for ( row = 0; row < SIZE; row++ )
{ 
    for ( int n = 0; n < enn; n++ )
    {
        for ( column = 0; column < SIZE; column++ )
        {
            for ( int m = 0; m < enn; m++ )
            {
                fprintf( outfileptr, "%i\t", inArray[row][column] );
            }
        }
        fputs( "\n", outfileptr );
    }
}
fclose( outfileptr );
```

But you can do it with 2 loops too. Your table has `SIZE*enn` rows and `SIZE*enn` colums:

```
for ( row = 0; row < SIZE*enn; row++ )
{ 
    for ( column = 0; column < SIZE*enn; column++ )
    {
        fprintf( outfileptr, "%i\t", inArray[row/enn][column/enn] );
    }
    fputs( "\n", outfileptr );
}
fclose( outfileptr );
```

Note: The outer loops print the rows of the table. There are `SIZE` rows and each row has to be printed `enn` times. Eache row is terminated by `\n`. The inner loops print the colums, becaus each row consists of colums. There are `SIZE` colums and each colums has to be printed `enn` times for each row. The table has `SIZE * enn * SIZE * enn` fields.

Comment: Clever! First solution is more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I intuit the logic behind it! This has tripped me up lots of times.

Comment: I think the first solution needs a fputs("\n", outfileptr) somewhere, but the second one works fine. @Rabbid76